# File input click event not fired after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

After some simplifications, code looks like this

```
$(function(){
  var x = $("<input type='file'>");
  $(document.body).append(x);
  x.trigger("click");
});
```

After page loads, nothing happens, but when I open console and call trigger("click") on it, it opens dialog as it should. What's the reason of first time event ignoring?

Use chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit)

Comment: what simplifications you made?  I guess your missing **try adding document.ready method**

Comment: when your selecting the file for uploading you want the function trigger to be called? Am i correct?

Comment: @Seraph, In my opinion, **Anonymous function** and **document.ready function** are different.
You should use your code inside $(document).ready();

Comment: I think the key is on the fact that you're falsely trying to trigger click on a string (`"<input type='file'>"`)...

Comment: I want to invoke file upload, thats all. Second, I don't try to invoke trigger on string, jquery parses html

Comment: @Natiq https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ its equivalent

Comment: @Seraph when I test that, it gives me `'<input type='file'>' is not a valid selector.` error in the console...

Comment: @webeno STO doesn't use jQuery ... so it's really not working, my example is dependant on jQuery

Comment: @Seraph what's STO?

Comment: I mean stack overflow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124168/discussion-between-webeno-and-seraph).

Answer (score 0):

Hi this trick only works on IExplorer. Input file can't be automatically triggered in (onload, pageload, document.ready...) due to security purpose